# How to call an async method in unity from a method that must stay on the main thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I have a method called `SendWithReplyAsync`, it uses `TaskCompletionSource` to signal when it is complete and return a reply from the server.

I am trying to get 2 replies from the server in a method that also needs to change scenes, change transforms, etc so it needs to be on the main thread, as I understand it.

This method is bound to the `OnClick()` of a ui button in unity:

```
public async void RequestLogin()
{
    var username = usernameField.text;
    var password = passwordField.text;
    var message  = new LoginRequest() { Username = username, Password = password };

    var reply = await client.SendWithReplyAsync<LoginResponse>(message);

    if (reply.Result)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Login success!");
        await worldManager.RequestSpawn();
    }
    else Debug.Log($"Login failed! {reply.Error}");
}
```

as you can see, there is a call to `await WorldManager.RequestSpawn();`

That method looks like this:

```
public async Task RequestSpawn()
{
    //Get the initial spawn zone and transform
    var spawnReply = await client.SendWithReplyAsync<PlayerSpawnResponse>(new PlayerSpawnRequest());

    //Load the correct zone
    SceneManager.LoadScene("TestingGround");

    //Move the player to the correct location
    var state = spawnReply.initialState;
    player.transform.position = state.Position.Value.ToVector3();
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, state.Rotation.Value, 0);

    //The last step is to get the visible entities at our position and create them before closing the loading screen
    var statesReply = await client.SendWithReplyAsync<InitialEntityStatesReply>(new InitialEntityStatesRequest());

    SpawnNewEntities(statesReply);
}
```

So when I click the button, I can see (server side) that all of the messages (the login request, the spawn request and the initial entity state request) are all making it. However, nothing happens in unity. No scene change and (obviously) no position or rotation update.

I have a feeling i am not understanding something about async/await when it comes to unity and my `RequestSpawn` method is not running on the main thread.

I tried using `client.SendWithReplyAsync(...).Result` and removing the `async` keyword on all the methods, but that just caused a deadlock. I read more about deadlocks on Stephen Cleary's blog [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) ( it seems his site consumes 100% cpu.. am I the only one?)

I am really not sure how to get this working.

In case you need them, here are the methods that send/receive messages:

```
public async Task<TReply> SendWithReplyAsync<TReply>(Message message) where TReply : Message
{
    var task = msgService.RegisterReplyHandler(message);
    Send(message);

    return (TReply)await task;
}

public Task<Message> RegisterReplyHandler(Message message, int timeout = MAX_REPLY_WAIT_MS)
{
    var replyToken = Guid.NewGuid();

    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Message>();
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(timeout);
    //TODO Make sure there is no leakage with the call to Token.Register() 
    tokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
    {
        completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
        if (replyTasks.ContainsKey(replyToken))
            replyTasks.Remove(replyToken);
    },
        false);

    replyTasks.Add(replyToken, completionSource);

    message.ReplyToken = replyToken;
    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

And here is where/how the tasks are completed:

```
private void HandleMessage<TMessage>(TMessage message, object sender = null) where TMessage : Message
{
    //Check if the message is in reply to a previously sent one.
    //If it is, we can complete the reply task with the result
    if (message.ReplyToken.HasValue &&
        replyTasks.TryGetValue(message.ReplyToken.Value, out TaskCompletionSource<Message> tcs) &&
        !tcs.Task.IsCanceled)
    {
        tcs.SetResult(message);
        return;
    }

    //The message is not a reply, so we can invoke the associated handlers as usual
    var messageType = message.GetType();
    if (messageHandlers.TryGetValue(messageType, out List<Delegate> handlers))
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            //If we have don't have a specific message type, we have to invoke the handler dynamically
            //If we do have a specific type, we can invoke the handler much faster with .Invoke()
            if (typeof(TMessage) == typeof(Message))
                handler.DynamicInvoke(sender, message);
            else
                ((Action<object, TMessage>)handler).Invoke(sender, message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError(string.Format("No handler found for message of type {0}", messageType.FullName));
        throw new NoHandlersException();
    }
}
```

*fingers crossed the legendary Stephen Cleary sees this*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using async/await via a recent version of Unity with '.NET 4.x Equivalent' set as the Scripting Runtime Version, then your `RequestSpawn()` method as written should be running on Unity's main thread. You can verify by calling:

```
Debug.Log(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

The following simple test loads the new scene correctly for me, using Unity 2018.2 (output below):

```
public async void HandleAsync()
{
    Debug.Log($"Foreground: {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    await WorkerAsync();
    Debug.Log($"Foreground: {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}

private async Task WorkerAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Debug.Log($"Worker: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    await Task.Run((System.Action)BackgroundWork);
    await Task.Delay(500);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
}

private void BackgroundWork()
{
    Debug.Log($"Background: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

Output:

> Foreground: 1
>
> Worker: 1
>
> Background: 48
>
> Foreground: 1

Comment: I added the bit that completes the reply tasks. The thing is, in other methods I have calls to the same function, `SendWithReplyAsync`, and they work just fine.

Comment: Have you ruled out problems like target scene is not included in your build, etc?

Comment: You know what, your example code helped me a lot. It helped me to realize my problem was not at all to do with async/await but rather that my networking code was producing an erroneous length prefix. Had you not done the legwork for me, i'd still be tearing my hair out of the above. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You can mark it correct if you think it addresses your original question sufficiently. :)

Answer (score -1):

try to do the async request with Coroutines and Callbacks,...

first, start a Coroutine....
in the routine u prepare and fire the request....
after this, u break the routine with this:

```
while(!request.isDone) {
    yield return null;
}
```

after u get a response, use a callback function to change your scene